# Heat Equation Steady state question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Say you have a slab of material occupying the region $0\leq x\leq a$.  Heat is supplied at a constant unit rate so the temperature $T(x,t)$ satisfies 
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= k \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} +1$$
The initial temperature is $0$, $x=0$ is maintained at zero temperature and face $x=a$ is thermally insulated.

1. What are the initial and boundary conditions?
2. How would you figure out the steady state solution $T_s(x,t)$?

Comment: This looks like homework... a) has nothing to do with the "+1", it's given in the last sentence of your description. b) The steady state is reached when $\partial T/\partial t = 0$, I think you know how to integrate the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

a) As specified by your question, the initial condition is $T(x,0) = 0$ and the boundary conditions are $T(0,t) = 0$ ($x=0$ maintained at 0), and $T_x(a,t) = 0$.

b) The steady-state solution is reached when $T_t(x,t) = 0$, so:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 T_s}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{1}{k} \implies 
\frac{\partial T_s}{\partial x} = - \frac{x}{k} + \mathrm{Const}_1(t)
$$

Evaluating the rhs at the boundary $x=a$ for all $t$ yields $\mathrm{Const_1(t)} = \frac{a}{k}$. This leads to:
$$
T_s(x,t) = \frac{ax}{k} - \frac{x^2}{2k} + \mathrm{Const}_2(t)
$$
and evaluating the rhs this time at the boundary $x=0$ for all $t$ yields $\mathrm{Const}_2(t) = 0$, which finally result in:
$$
T_s(x,t) = \frac{x}{k}\left( a - \frac{x}{2} \right)
$$